# Reading data in batches from an excel file every 6000 milliseconds

Tags: java, excel, batch-processing

I have an excel file that contains some records. My intention is to read data from this file into my database after every 6000 milliseconds. I have successfully been able to read the first batch after the first 6000 milliseconds. For the first batch, about 10 records were read. My challenge is how to set my code to fetch the next batch without reading the previous records that have been read. How do i set my code to read the next batch without it reading the previous 10 records?

Below is the code snippet:

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputExcel);
// All the data is contained in the first sheet
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    if (endTime - startTime >= 6000)
        break;
    for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (endTime - startTime >= 6000)
            break;
        if (j == 7) {
            rowBuffer[j] = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        } else {
            rowBuffer[j] = sheet.getCell(j, i).getContents();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you break the batch based on time elapsed track the , store the row number,column no: into 2 temp variables which is being read, then start from temp row,temp column in the next batch

Comment: Yeah. Store them into temp variables. Also, I would recommend using Java timers